# can I use array as depenedency in useEffect() in react?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, next.js

using array as a dependency in useEffect() hook in react.

```
const [productCategories, setproductCategories] = useState([]);


useEffect(() => {
    // set something..
    if(categories){
      const filtered = categories.filter((c)=>c.available);
      setproductCategories(filtered);
    }
  }, [categories]);
```

here **categories** is already an array coming from the server.
I want, if this category changes set the productCategories state.
when I tried this it goes into infinite calling.

Comment: Shouldn't you be using productCategories instead of categories????

Comment: Issue i cans see that even if categories is an [] array  the if(categories) will become conditionally true and inside you are calling `setproductCategories` which will update cause re render again -> thus causing infinite loop

Comment: I don't see the point of using the ```useEffect```  if you are getting the ```categories``` from the server. You can just simply do this    ```const [productCategories, setproductCategories] = useState(() =>
    categories.filter((c) => c.available)
  );```

Answer (score 0):

instead of
[categories]
use [JSON.stringify(categories)]
as array reference changes it goes in infinite loop, better try this.

Answer (score 0):

you can use instead:

```
const [productCategories, setproductCategories] = useState([]);

useEffect(() => {
    // set something..
    if(categories){
      const filtered = categories.filter((c)=>c.available);
     // when productCategories update
     // your component gonne re-render
      setproductCategories(filtered);
    }
  }, [productCategories]);
```

Comment: but productCategories is also array, and it will go in an infinite loop.